# Switch off git integration in Sublime Text 3.2

Tags: git, sublimetext3

If I want to switch off the GIT integration (aka the slime green line) on the left hand gutter in Sublime text, I just need to switch it to false:

```
26    "show_git_status": false
```

However, when setting that in the Preferences, I get the error:

*Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected character, expected a comma or closing brackets in Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings:26:2*

Clearly I'm a comma or bracket(s) short, but I don't know where or what format it should be. Can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: The green line in the gutter is from the incremental diff. If you don't want that, you need to set `mini_diff` to `false`. The git integration works independently of the mini diff; mini diff also applies to files not under git.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are missing a comma there in line 26, it should be:

```
 "show_git_status": false,
```

After each option there must be either a comma, indicating that there are more config parameters remaining, or a closing bracket `}`.

Comment: It's the line above that needed the comma, but I realised that was where I was going wrong :)

Comment: And this is why I can't stand *json*...

Answer (score 3):

Since you added a line, it seems that you just forgot to add a comma at the end of the **previous** line.

OK :

```
{
    "some_property": value,
    "some_other_property": value,
    "show_git_status": false
}
```

NOT OK :

```
{
    "some_property": value,
    "some_other_property": value
    "show_git_status": false
}
```