# GIT integration in Sublime Text 3.2 still showing up

Tags: git, sublimetext3

Further to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55325394/switch-off-git-integration-in-sublime-text-3-2/55325522#55325522), why is the green GIT line still showing up with

```
 "show_git_status": false,
```

added to my preferences file in Sublime Text 3.2?
And yes, I have restarted Sublime (as well as a reboot)

Comment: Further to your original question, what you want to turn off is the incremental diff, not  git status; git status shows you the status of files in the side bar. Set `mini_diff` to `false` if you don't want incremental diff.

Answer (score 6):

As from the setting file, you need both:

```
// Shows git repository information next to files in sidebar and in
// the status bar. Sublime Text has to be restarted for this to take
// effect.
"show_git_status": false,
```

and

```
// Indicate modified lines in the gutter
// - true: Enables modified line indicators on all files
// - "auto": Enables modified line indicators on tracked files within Git
// - false: Disables modified line indicators
"mini_diff": false,
```

To disable all the git utilities.

*Note: A restart of sublime is required!*